# Documentation of math functions in Swift 3

Tags: function, swift3

I know that Swift 3 includes functions like ceil and floor, because I've tried them and they compile and execute.  But I've been unable to find any mention of them in the Apple reference documentation.  I'd like to know what other math functions are provided.  Where should I look?

Comment: Have you googled "swift documentation"? I imagine that should yield many results.

Comment: Of course I have.  I'm looking on the developer.apple.com pages.  I've followed the links for API Reference, for Swift Standard Library, for the Foundation Framework.  I've used the Search function too.  I can find "sqrt" using search, but I can't find ceil the same way.

Comment: I was wrong.  I can search for `ceil` just as I can search for `sqrt`.  The search takes me to a page for the Objective-C function `double ceil(double);` Up at the top of the page is the notation `Kernel > ceil`, so I assume that `ceil` is part of the Kernel library.  My expectation is that somewhere in the API reference documentation is a page that lists `sqrt` and `sin` and `ceil` and `pow` and dozens of other functions.  But when I follow the link to the Kernel framework, it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift

Answer (score 0):

I am using Swift 4.1 and XCode 9.3. I am just starting out. I, too, found it hard to locate information on the math functions, but in the end I had some success.

The math functions can be found in the Developer Document browser by opening Core Graphics > Core Graphics Functions in the sidebar. To search for a specific function, say `sin`, type the functions name and a left parenthesis, e.g., `sin(`, in the browser's search field. (For some of the functions you can get away with omitting the parenthesis).

Another way to find documentation for these functions is launch Terminal and type `man math`. Personally, I find this easier than using the XCode browser.